# case when for getting a scalar value using linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq

I want to do this with Linq:

```
select when name<>'' then name else username end displayname from users where id = 1
```

I know how to select a scalar value with linq

```
   string name = from u in users
               select new {u.name}.SingleOrDefault();
```

but how can I implement case when to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should help:

```
 string name = (from u in users
               select new 
               {
                  Name = u.name != "" ? u.name : u.username
               }).SingleOrDefault();
```

You can also use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`

Answer (score 1):

```
var resul = users.Where(x => new { Name = u.name != "" ? u.name : u.username });
```

Comment: you can use SingleOrDefault() for sing result